# How to build an HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to get the correct html format with jQuery.
My output at the moment is in one row

- Note / 2.5 / 1

But I want value among each other

- Note
- 2.5
- 1

This is my html table construct

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="myTable">
</table>
```

And here is my jQuery function

```
$('#myTable').empty();


            $('#myTable').append('<tbody>')
            $('#myTable').append('<tr>')
            $('#myTable').append('<th>'+ "Note" +'</th>')
            $('#myTable').append('</tr>')
            $.each(data, function(index, valueAusData){


                $('#myTable').append('<tr>')
                $('#myTable').append('<td>'+ valueAusData.note+'</td>')
                $('#myTable').append('</tr>')
            });
            $('#myTable').append('</tbody>')
```

Comment: There is no php code to justify the `laravel` tag

Comment: Sounds like you rather want a simple _list_ (`ul`/ `ol`) of items (`li`), and not a table ...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$('#myTable').empty();
$('#myTable').append('<thead><tr><th>Note</th></tr></thead>');
$('#myTable').append('<tbody></tbody>');
$.each(data, function(index, valueAusData){
    $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + valueAusData.note + '</td></tr>');
});
```